# TOC in Rmd not appearing when including HTML documents

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, kable

I am running into an issue where the TOC is not appearing in my HTML output of an Rmd if I include HTML documents from certain source. For example, if I make a table with `kable` and save to an HTML:

```
library(kableExtra)

tbl <- kable(mtcars) %>% 
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", font_size = 12)

save_kable(tbl, file = "testkable_tbl.html")
```

Then try and read the HTML into an Rmd:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "User"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  html_document:
   toc: TRUE
   toc_depth: 4
   toc_float: TRUE
---

# hello

```{r}
htmltools::includeHTML("testkable_tbl.html")
```
````

The TOC does not appear.
This issue is not exclusive to `kable` as I have had this issue including HTML documents from other sources.

Why does this issue appear with some HTML documents and not others (no issues with including HTML documents made with `gt`)? Is there a work around to include HTML tables from `kable` and other sources in my Rmd without the TOC disappearing?